# Determine parameter from which on there is no more root for a given function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

Let $\gamma>0$ be a real number and $\Phi(r)=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{\pi}{4}\left(H_0(r/2)-Y_0(r/2)\right)$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, where $H_0$ is the Struve function of order zero and $Y_0$ is the Bessel function of second kind of order zero.

My goal is to find $\gamma_c$ such that for all $\gamma\geq\gamma_c$ the function $\Phi(r)-\frac{\gamma}{r^2}\leq0$ for all $r\in[0,\infty)$.
Plots suggest that the critical $\gamma_c$ is about $0.5$. The root in this regime is about $r_0\approx 0.5$.

Comment: Do you mean `1/r - (StruveH[0, r/2] - BesselK[0, r/2]) Pi/4`, or something else?  `Y0` typically is used to represent a Bessel function, not a modified Bessel function.

Comment: My bad, I meant $Y_0$, the Bessel function of second kind of order zero.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining

```
f = 1/r - (StruveH[0, r/2] - BesselY[0, r/2]) Pi/4
```

the maximum value that f r^2 assumes is

```
NMaximize[{f r^2, r > 0}, r]
(* {0.498508, {r -> 2.58341}} *)
```

Thus, the critical value of `γ` is `0.498508`.  The following illustrates this maximum.

```
Plot[r^2 f, {r, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {r, "f"}]
```

[image]